# Not able to calculate the time difference properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I think there is some format issue in my query due to which i am not able to calculate the `TIMEDIFF()`. When give hard coded date direct into query such as `2016-09-10` it works. But when i store date in a variable it does not works. In MySQL date is already stored in `TimeStamp` data type field. Please check the code below.

```
$from_date=date_format(date_create("2020-04-02 17:49:5"),"Y-m-d");
$to_date=date_format(date_create("2020-08-08 18:49:5"),"Y-m-d");
```

```
SELECT A1.u_id_fk, 
       A3.full_name, 
       A1.created AS check_in_at, 
       A2.created AS check_out_at, 
       TIMEDIFF(A2.created, A1.created) AS total_time 
FROM timesheet AS A1 
INNER JOIN timesheet AS A2 ON A1.u_id_fk = A2.u_id_fk 
                          AND DATE(A1.created) = DATE(A2.created) 
INNER JOIN users A3 on A1.u_id_fk=A3.u_id 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND A1.status = 'Check-In' 
  AND A2.status = 'Check-Out' 
  AND DATE(A1.created) BETWEEN :todate AND :fromdate 
  AND DATE(A2.created) BETWEEN :todate AND :fromdate 
ORDER BY A1.created DESC
```

```
$user_login->execute(["todate"=>$to_date,"fromdate"=>$from_Date]);
```

**I want Output Results like below** filtering results by giving from date and to date in `Y-m-d` format

**Results**

```
u_id_fk         check_in_at            check_out_at           total_time

EMP0002         2016-08-21 14:52:48    2016-08-21 21:09:18    06:16:30
EMP0001         2016-08-20 09:30:30    2016-08-20 18:15:00    08:44:30
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Okay let me edit my question i am posting sample output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated my question by adding the output sample.

Comment: 1) Provided query must give shown result (except full_name which is not shown). 2) In the query the condition `AND DATE(A2.created) BETWEEN :todate AND :fromdate` is excess (see joining condition).

Comment: *i have updated my question by adding the output sample.* But where is sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which results in shown output?